# How to get rid of unused jfsCommit processes?

Tags: filesystem

On a Dell Poweredge T620 with Xeon hexacore processor, i notice that there are 14 extraneous processes for the jfs filesystem. On another server, there are similar processes for the xfs filesystem as well.

Though they don't cause any problem or significant load, i would like to get rid of these processes since i use neither jfs nor xfs.

Here are the relevant parts of the ps ax output:

```
31611 ?        S      0:00 [jfsIO]
31612 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31613 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31614 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31615 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31616 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31617 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31618 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31619 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31620 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31621 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31622 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31623 ?        S      0:00 [jfsCommit]
31624 ?        S      0:00 [jfsSync]

>uname -a 
Linux ada 2.6.32-41-server #89-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27 22:33:31 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need them? I mean, do you want me to post an answer about how to kill the processes and how to completely remove them so as not to run again?

Comment: I will never use jfs on this server. I would like a clean way of preventing them from starting up, without causing any unwanted side effects. This could be removing a package, disabling the right startup process in init.d or perhaps some switch either in a file in /etc/defaults or whatever. What i don't want is some kludge in rc.local ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you are not using JFS/XFS, these kernel processes exist if the JFS/XFS kernel modules are loaded. Assuming you're using a recent stock kernel, these kernel modules are `.ko` modules, so to prevent them from loading all you need to do is blacklist `jfs` and `xfs` inside `/etc/modprobe.d`

If you are using a kernel that has these modules built-in, the only way to remove them is at runtime with an `rmmod` or `modprobe -r` -- in that case, those would have to go into a startup script.

To find out whether yours are modular or built-in, just do a `sudo updatedb` and `locate jfs.ko`, `locate xfs.ko`. If results in the `/lib/modules/` directory are returned, they are modular; otherwise, they're built-in.

Could you edit the question with the output of `uname -a`?