# Unknown processes starting with jfs and xfs

Tags: process

Today, I checked the running processes on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.
There are 9 processes named *jfsCommit*, *jfsSync* and *jfsIO*.

I wanted to ask what they are used for because I never saw them before and if/how I can remove them if needed.
Also there are some processes starting with *xfs* which I never had before.

Thank you!

Output of df -T

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4     480719568 2315116 453985228   1% /
udev           devtmpfs   1994316       4   1994312   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       801252     288    800964   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      2003128       0   2003128   0% /run/shm
```

Comment: Looks like IBM's journaled filesystem. What is your output of `df -T`?

Comment: @konapun added it to first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167867/how-to-get-rid-of-unused-jfscommit-processes).

> Even if you are not using JFS/XFS, these kernel processes exist if the JFS/XFS kernel modules are loaded. Assuming you're using a recent stock kernel, these kernel modules are .ko modules, so to prevent them from loading all you need to do is blacklist jfs and xfs inside /etc/modprobe.d
>
> If you are using a kernel that has these modules built-in, the only way to remove them is at runtime with an rmmod or modprobe -r -- in that case, those would have to go into a startup script.
>
> To find out whether yours are modular or built-in, just do a sudo updatedb and locate jfs.ko, locate xfs.ko. If results in the /lib/modules/ directory are returned, they are modular; otherwise, they're built-in.